# Salesforce Add A Button/ Link Against Phone Numbers

Tags: browser, salesforce, apex-code, phone-number

In Salesforce, is it possible to add a button/ link against the Phone numbers on contact/ lead record's detail page?
I need this to implement something like Skype's Click-To-Call browser extension.

Does it require a browser extension? Can it be done w/o an extension?

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this if you have a CTI adapter installed. Salesforce has demo CTI adapter that you can install and play around with.

Here is the link to a YouTube video of the demo CTI adapter: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36k7iwnYYfM

Here is the link to the Salesforce CTI toolkit, it contains the link to the demo CTI adapter that you can download: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/CTI_Toolkit